# Weird Language Behavior of Terminator/Terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, language-support, terminator

For some reason my Terminator now seems to have 3 languages in use. Yes, **three**:

[image: Terminator Settings]

As you can see, there are Spanish, English and German all at the same time.

I think the English ones probably result from incomplete translations of Terminator, which I understand, but still there is the mix-up of Spanish and German.

Also, both Spanish and German can be seen when I run certain commands, such as the following, where the last sentence is in German:

[image: Command Output]

Systemwide my language is German. I used Spanish before but I've already changed that about 2 months ago. I have no idea what could be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Some settings from Spanish ,like currency settings probably have stayed. You can use `LC_ALL=C nohup terminator &` to launch new window with English only and close old one . Use it for now as workaround untill you find a fix.

Comment: Probably won't solve your problem but improves your system's language support: The first thing I'd do is to go to `Language Support`. If you launch it and your language packages are incomplete, it tells you (opens a separate window so you can't overlook it) and offers you to install them.

Comment: @UTF-8 Yeah, I changed settings via Language Support, and all packages seem to be installed.

Comment: @Serg I think I changed all relevant settings in Language Support to German. Maybe there are some other places for such settings as well?

Comment: @JIXiang what does `printenv | grep LC` tell you ?

Comment: @Serg Everything is `de_DE.UTF-8`

Comment: @JIXiang well, that's odd. I personally have no ideas for this. MAybe someone else will come up with better ideas

Comment: What's the value of your `$LANGUAGE`? This environmet variable might contain a colon-separated languages in the order of preference. I guess you'll see something like `de:es` there.

Comment: @egmont That's right. So all those Spanish texts are due to the corresponding German texts being not available in the first place, and thus the language second in the list took over?

Comment: Yup, I'll add a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple language can show up if you have your `LANGUAGE` variable set to a colon-separated list of languages, e.g. `de:es`. In this case apps using the gettext engine (that's almost all utilities that have translations) try to pick German, but then fall back to Spanish for each string that is missing its German translation. Should the Spanish translation also be missing for a certain string, the final fallback is always (American) English.

See e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/The-LANGUAGE-variable.html for details. In particular, as pointed out on that page: "you still need to have LANG (or LC_ALL) set to the primary language".